# React component inside Angular app - compilation error

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use the react library _fortune-sheet_ (https://github.com/ruilisi/fortune-sheet) inside my angular project.
I did a small example to see how it works, I created a container (wrapper) and it works with my sample.

However, when I import the lib with: import { Workbook } from '@fortune-sheet/react'
And when I use it:

```
    private render() {
    if (!this.hasViewLoaded) {
      return;
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(Workbook),
      document.getElementById(this.rootId)
    );
```

It looks like a compilation error due to code coming from the lib, here is the stack:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/api/index.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/api/index.d.ts(1,36): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/api/index.d.ts(2,1): error TS1128:     Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/api/index.d.ts(2,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/formula.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/formula.d.ts(1,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/selection.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/selection.d.ts(1,68): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/text.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@fortune-sheet/core/dist/modules/text.d.ts(1,30): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the typescript version. To be able to use it I was forced to upgrade the typescript version to 3.8 (to have the Type-Only Imports and Exports feature)
But the current angular version project (7.1 allows may 3.3 typescript version) does not support this ts version, I had to upgrade to Angular 9 - then 13 - to use typescript version 3.8.3, and finally use "typescript": "~4.6.4",